Survey 123 Connect - Constraints, answer not from file list
I'm trying to make a Survey using Survey 123 connect,
I want my user to enter a new ID but I want to make sure that the new ID is not the same as an exiting ID in a CSV file,
e.g I want the constraint to be Answer cannot equal field 1 in ID.csv,
How can I do this?
